# 405 error while generating a pdf in Django3

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

I followed this [coadingforentrepreneurs](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/html-template-to-pdf-in-django/) tutorial to generate pdfs and it works fine.

The issue is when i use a post request to generate a pdf it shows me a 405 error. I am using post method to access customer-id to generate a invoice.

Here is my GeneratePDF class

```
class GeneratePDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
            if request.method == 'POST':
                template = get_template('head/invoice.html')
                context = {
                "customer":"aaaa"
                }
                html = template.render(context)
                pdf = render_to_pdf('head/invoice.html', context)
                if pdf:
                    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
                    filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %("12341231")
                    content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
                    download = request.GET.get("download")
                if download:
                    content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
                response['Content-Disposition'] = content
                return response
            
            template = get_template('head/invoice.html')
            context = {
                "customer":"aaaa"
            }
            html = template.render(context)
            pdf = render_to_pdf('head/invoice.html', context)
            if pdf:
                response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
                filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %("12341231")
                content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
                download = request.GET.get("download")
                if download:
                    content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
                response['Content-Disposition'] = content
                return response
```

I have not edited any other files

Here is the response from the server

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /employee/customer_printbill/
Method Not Allowed: /employee/customer_printbill/
```

I am a beginner in django and i am unable to resolve this issue. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing function based and class based views. You should define `post` method in your class based view, and request will be dispatched to that `post` method. And thus you do not need to check if `request.method` is `POST` in your `get` method, because `POST` request will be handled by your `post` method. Please see [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this. It was dumb of me to check request.method on get method